# In scala does passing a var to a "=> T" type work?

Tags: scala

Given a method with the signature

```
def declareParam[T](name: String, setter: T => _, getter: => T): Unit
```

and the consuming code

```
var v = 1
params.declareParam("someName", v_=, v)
```

everything will successfully compile, but I'm new enough to scala that I don't know if it will work as I expect.  If I change v and later some other code gets the declared parameter and calls the stored getter will it return the new value or will it return 1 (the value when I called declareParam)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works only in class definition.

In this case `var v` is not a variable, but a field.

Try this:

```
{
  var v = 1
  params.declareParam("someName", v_=, v)
}
```

You'll get a compilation error.

`var` field is implemented using getter and setter methods. So you have 2 methods in scope: `def v_=(i: Int): Unit` and `def v(): Int`.

Scala compiler can implicitly convert method to function, for instance:

```
(1 to 10).foreach{println}
```

here `println` is a method from `Predef` object. Compiler creates a function like this:

```
(1 to 10).foreach{ i => Predef.println(i)}
```

So your code means this:

```
params.declareParam("someName", i => this.v_=(i), () => this.v)
```